# Retrieving the correct model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to edit data from a model, but it keeps listing the User id instead of its own id. Why is that?

```
<% provide(:title, 'Activations') %>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
<% if @user.activations.present? %>
  <h3>Activations (<%= @user.activations.count %>)</h3>
  <ol class="activations">
    <%= render @activation %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @activation %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

This is part of the partial that is being rendered

```
<span class="user"><%= link_to activation.id, edit_activation_path %></span>
```

I've tried passing `edit_activation_path(params[:id])`The activation id is being listed correctly, but I don't know how to set the edit path with the id from the activation model.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the model object to the link helper.

`edit_activation_path(activation)`.